# Android Studio xml preview issue failed to initialize editor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-dolphin

After Update android studio **dolphin** my old projects xml preview not showing views. Is anyone facing same issue? And have done solution then please share it here.
It's run perfectly fine but preview not working.

What I did tried?

- File -> Invalidate Cashes / Restart
- Delete build , idea , gradle folder
- Restart PC and android studio

but none of that solved my problem.

[image: error image]
[image: not showing]

Comment: @MansoorMalik tried but still have same problem

Comment: did you try complete uninstall then download and install again instead of update?

Comment: Same issue I am facing

Comment: Invalidate caches is not working. This update is very bad

Comment: I have the same issued when updating to dolphin, very bad update, anyone solve it

Comment: same issue. nothing worked. changing theme, reinstalling sdsk tools, emulators, update again, cache delete, restart....very bad situation

Comment: @FabianK You got any error? Upgrade Your gradle to latest if not already.

Comment: In my case, the issue only happens with any XML file that contains a custom view. Setting defStyleAttr = 0 should resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm suffering from same issue/bug.  What I did so far?

### Attempt 1

- File -> `Sync Project with gradle files`
- File -> `Invalid catch and Restart`.
- Delete build folder idea and `.gradle` folder.
- Restart Android studio and restarted my pc as well.
  This will do solve in one of the my project which is only 5 screen project. But not solved in my other old projects which are more than 5 year old.

### Attempt 2

Tried all step from attempt 1 Also tried what siregar2103 answered

- File -> **Repair IDE** but still have same problem ,But Repair IDE did solve my other project issue/bug.

### Attempt 3

All from Attempt 1 and 2 but not solve in my main project so I decided to upgrade my years old project to latest one.
I did upgrade my Gradle from `4.1.3 to 7.3.0`
Update all dependency to latest one but I face many error while doing that.
Hilt error and other errors too. Which I'm going to mention below.
For Hilt I did removed all old Hilt related library and and below

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.42"     
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.43.2"     
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.42"     
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2"     
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0'     
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"     
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'     
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.1"
```

---

In `build.gradle` file (not `.app` level)

- `id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.43.2' apply false`

**Important note**: I did add  `implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.1"` dependency because I got

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value
> by **SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY** error in runtime.

---

Other Error which I faced is

> Exception is:
> com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException:
> `lateinit property _buildFeatureValues has not been initialized`

For this I did build gradle using command line and it give me full error which I didn't get when I directly build don't know why? But It's through error related flat dir and aar file so I did removed **flat dir** code and change **aar file implementation code** now It's started to build and my app started to install.
Now still some of my file not rendering and that because of I'm using custom `attr` from style so I'm trying to figuring out why it's happening and I'll update this answer when I find solution for that.
So using above my 60% xml files preview start showing in my old projects. For 40% screen I have to change my default theme to **custom theme in preview of xml** so it can start rendering.

---

- Repair IDE
- Upgrade your code to latest `Android Gradle Plugin`

This 2 step should solve your problem. And build using command line for more error related details.

Comment: I did upgrade gradle but still got error `_buildFeatureValues ` so building using command line did the trick and I had problem aar files are not resolved. But I still not understand why `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.1` is required because I have same error `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY ` ?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I have upgraded the project AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) and then restart the android studio.

Problem Solved.

Comment: @AndroidDev, I hope your issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks .Yes It is facing other error after upgrading gradle that is solved by bhavin patel's answer.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Repair IDE]

Have you try to using Repair IDE? It works for me

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue when upgrading to Dolphin. I was able to solve this by changing the preview's theme from App.Starting [default] to my app's theme.

[image]

Comment: After trying this the issue is still the same.

Comment: no solution for me. whatever theme

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the gradle and sync files. It work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The XML file in your project may contain an error. The reason may be a font issue or a file not linking correctly with your XML layout.

This is for your reference on how to find errors.

[image: This is for your reference on how to find errors.]

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check what Layout Inspectors you have enabled in Android Studio and try to let only the API 29-30 inspector active.

[image]

Comment: No, whatever version is not running. Whatever style is choosen.

Answer (score 0):

In my case if in xml custom views have used that my preview screen not show views if I remove or comment custom views in xml layout after that the preview screen show other view perfectly

I know removing custom layouts not solution.

for solve this issue I do following steps

First I just update Gradle plugin version to `7.3.0` from **setting project structure** *(No working)*

after that I also update `com.google.gms:google-services` version to `4.3.14`

now every things work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have upgraded Android Gradle Plugin when update is popUp and then restart the android studio.

My Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking as well for a soluition till now.
From what i see, it has something to do with
AGP or Cardview (Layouts). Many code snipeets relate to this issue.

I am trying to update the AGP version, but it seems, that the enveronmet is more broken than that.
I get as well an empty Field for the gradle version and plugin under settings.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone can not fix this issue, i'm just need to update gradle version and buildtool

buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Dependencies.kt

```
object BuildPlugins {
    object Versions {
        const val buildToolVersion = "7.3.0" //lower version seem not work
```

and change to 7.4 in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
```